# IllegalStateException in nested quote and unquote

Tags: clojure, macros

Here is an example from joy of clojure:

```
(let [x 9, y '(- x)]
  (println `y)
  (println ``y)
  (println ``~y)
  (println ``~~y))
```

Output from repl:

```
typedclj.macros/y
(quote typedclj.macros/y)
typedclj.macros/y
(- x)
```

If I rearrange the order of quote/unquote a bit, results are still the same (I am wondering why):

```
(let [x 9, y '(- x)]
  (println `y)
  (println ``y)
  (println `~`y)
  (println `~`~y))
```

But if I put the tilde in front:

```
(let [x 9, y '(- x)]
  (println `y)
  (println ``y)
  (println `~`y)
  (println ~``~y))
```

I get a strange error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'clojure.core/unquote, compiling:(/Users/kaiyin/personal_config_bin_files/workspace/typedclj/src/typedclj/macros.clj:1:25)
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you're trying to `unquote` outside of a `syntax-quote`, and that doesn't make sense.

More details:

This error is generated from the final println. Observe that

```
(println ~``~y)
```

expands to

```
(println (unquote (syntax-quote (syntax-quote (unquote y))))
```

This happens by the virtue of `~` and the backtick character being reader macros. The expansion `unquote` is not actually a normal function or a macro. It's a special form which is defined only inside of a `syntax-quote`. You can see this in the compiler source, in [LispReader.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/41af6b24dd5be8bd62dc2b463bc53b55e18cd1e5/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L888). When you use it outside of a `syntax-quote` form, the reader macro has still happened but there's no such function as 'unquote'. There is only a bare `(def unquote)` in core.clj (the very first definition).

When you do a `def` like that, you end up with a var whose initial binding is an instance of the class `cloure.lang.Unbound` (it's one of the [constructors](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/41af6b24dd5be8bd62dc2b463bc53b55e18cd1e5/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java#L170) on `clojure.lang.Var`. This subclasses `clojure.lang.AFn` but doesn't specify any arities; so every invocation of it as a function calls [`throwarity`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/41af6b24dd5be8bd62dc2b463bc53b55e18cd1e5/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java#L31), giving you this exception.